# How to set up aria-live="assertive" and role="alert" in a nested structure?

Tags: html, accessibility, nvda, aria-live

I have a big web page, and in which after a successful submission of a form, it starts showing up a success/failure message, and we want NVDA to automatically read the same as soon as Submit button is clicked. I've tried the basic recommendations to add aria-live and role attributes, but its not working. Here is the snippet:

```
<p class="mb-hidden" ref={(el) => (this.messageBar = el as HTMLParagraphElement)}>
  <div aria-live="assertive" id ="testID" role="alert">
    <span class="classRed" id="container2" ref={(el) => (this.message = el as HTMLSpanElement)}></span>
  </div>
</p>
```

The span is getting updated with the message after a Submit button is clicked, but NVDA is not reading the message automatically.

Comment: remove `role="alert"`, you already have `aria-live="assertive"` so that is unnecessary (or vice versa). Secondly are you adding multiple `aria-live` regions? If you are adding them rather that updating the contents of the `aria-live` region this is likely to be the cause of your issue as dynamically added `aria-live` regions are problematic. So for clarity, have one `aria-live="assertive"` region and instead change the contents of that region and it should work correctly.